# VB.NET DataTable - Getting the first "n" items of a column without using a loop

Tags: vb.net, datatable

I have a DataTable `dt`and need to store the first `n` items of a certain column in an integer array. I know it's easy to do this with a loop like this:

```
Dim array(n-1) As Integer
For i As Integer = 0 To n-1
    array(i) = dt.Rows(i).Item("columName")
Next
```

Nonetheless, is there a more convenient way to store these items in the array?

Comment: What do you consider inconvenient about the way you're doing it? Seems like a fine solution.

Comment: I thought there might be a one-liner for doing that - which would make my code more readable, since I have to run these lines a bunch of times.

Comment: LINQ is one line if you want `(From row In dt Select row.Field(Of Int32)("columName") Take 10).ToArray()`. But that makes it not more efficient than a loop. Choose the most readable and maintainable approach.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

"Without using a loop" is impossible since there is no magic way to retrieve items from a collection without looping it. However, maybe you think that LINQ does not use loops:

```
Dim columNameValues = From row In dt
                      Select row.Field(Of Int32)("columName")
Dim array As Int32() = columNameValues.ToArray()
```

Gets all values from all rows, if you want to get `n` values use `Enumerable.Take`:

```
Dim array As Int32() = columNameValues.Take(n).ToArray()
```

In VB.NET you can even use `Take` in a LINQ query:

```
Dim first10Values = From row In dt
                    Select row.Field(Of Int32)("columName")
                    Take 10
```

For what it's worth, as Barry has mentioned it *is* technically possible to get `n` items from a collection without using a loop, but see yourself:

```
Dim value1 As Int32 = dt.Rows(0).Field(Of Int32)("columName")
Dim value2 As Int32 = dt.Rows(1).Field(Of Int32)("columName")
Dim value3 As Int32 = dt.Rows(2).Field(Of Int32)("columName")
' ..... '
Dim value10 As Int32 = dt.Rows(9).Field(Of Int32)("columName")
```

You could add them to a `List(Of Int32)`, but that's just for demonstration purposes anyway.

Comment: +1 for `"Without using a loop" is impossible since there is not magic way to retrieve items from a collection without looping it`.

Comment: +1 for the post, but technically there *is* a way to "*retrieve items from a collection without looping*", though it is decidedly non-magical and about as inelegant as it gets: `If (n<=1) array(1) = dt.Rows(1).Item("columName"); If (n<=2) array(2) = dt.Rows(1).Item("columName"); ...`  Ugh.  But still, not looping.

Comment: No worries, it's a nit anyway.